# Sklearn: Return custom transformer output

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am working on ML project. During feature engineering, I have created custom datetime transformer to extract new fields like day, month, etc.

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

import pandas as pd

class DateTimeTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    format = {
        "A": "d_m_y_h_m_s", # new columns: 6
        "B": "d_m_y" # new columns: 3
    }

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.count_ = 0
        self.format_ = DateTimeTransformer.format

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        
        X_temp = pd.DataFrame()

        for column in X.columns.tolist():

            X_ = pd.DataFrame()
            X[column] = pd.to_datetime(X[column], dayfirst=True)
            format = self.format_[column]

            match format:
                case "d_m_y_h_m_s":
                    X_["day"] = X[column].dt.day
                    X_["month"] = X[column].dt.month
                    X_["year"] = X[column].dt.year
                    X_["hour"] = X[column].dt.hour
                    X_["minute"] = X[column].dt.minute
                    X_["second"] = X[column].dt.second

                    self.count_ += 6
                case "d_m_y":
                    X_["d"] = X[column].dt.day
                    X_["m"] = X[column].dt.month
                    X_["y"] = X[column].dt.year

                    self.count_ += 3
                case "h_m_s":
                    X_["h"] = X[column].dt.hour
                    X_["m"] = X[column].dt.minute
                    X_["s"] = X[column].dt.second

                    self.count_ += 3

            X_temp = pd.concat([X_temp, X_], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

        return X_temp

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"New columns created {self.count_}"
```

**Input**

```
d = {
    "A": ["10/4/2023 4:4:4", "11/4/2023 3:3:3", "12/4/2023 2:2:2", "13/4/2023 1:1:1"],
    "B": ["15/4/2023", "16/4/2023", "17/4/2023", "18/4/2023"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [("datetime", DateTimeTransformer(), ["A", "B"])],
)

ct.fit(df)

new_df = ct.transform(df)

print(new_df)

for n,t,c in ct.transformers_:
    print(t)
```

While performing transformations, I am trying to return number of newly created columns for above eg

```
for `d_m_y_h_m_s` new columns 6
for `d_m_y` new columns 3

so total new columns as 9
```

But getting wrong output as double the value i.e 18

**Current output**

```
[[  10    4 2023    4    4    4   15    4 2023]
 [  11    4 2023    3    3    3   16    4 2023]
 [  12    4 2023    2    2    2   17    4 2023]
 [  13    4 2023    1    1    1   18    4 2023]]
New columns created 18    # Wrong count should be 9
```

What I am missing?

Comment: it seems that doing the `fit` and `transform` apart is the cause, doing it at once with `new_df = ct.fit_transform(df)` it will give you 9 and remove this line `ct.fit(df)`

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks. Using `new_df = ct.fit_transform(df)` giving correct output. My purpose to use separate `fit()` and `transform()` to make sure it will work on `dev and test set`. Based on this, do we always call `fit_transform()` on `train set`. While writing this transformer, I browsed several custom examples, and all of them were returing `return self` in `fit` and all logic in `transform`. In general, can you explain which part of logic should go in `fit` and `transform` respectively with respect to my above transformer or this way is ok?

Comment: Ok, not sure exactly what is the best practice here, but in the `fit` function, do the loop `for column in X.columns.tolist():`, get the format then do the `match format: case...` with only the line `self.count_+=...` in it, then in the transform, remove the `self.count_` lines. I believe that once fit is performed, you can't pass a dataframe that does not have the same structure (or an error occurs) so the count should stay at 9 and only dataframe with same structure will pass to give the good number of columns in the transform result

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks.After using `fit_transform()` on `train`, I tried transforming the `dev` set and was getting wrong count. So I did a hack(testing purpose) I reset the `count` to 0 outside of that loop like this `if self.count_:; self.temp_count_ = self.count_; self.count_ = 0;`. But the way you suggested is making more sense than above hack and is more full proof.